# JSCH expection handling - process error result from Catch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, jsch

i have written a program to connect to ssh server using JSCH lib, the program runs well.
in the catch block i have used

```
catch(JSchException ee)
{
  ....
}
```

when error occurs i get these messages,

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
```

now i need to display the error message in a dialog box. for each type of error i have to display different output. plz guide me how to process these exceptions and to differentiate them..

Comment: Have you checked http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException.html#getCause%28%29 ?

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i am newbie in programming, any examples will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your server seems to be [unreachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html): "`No route to host`" so your client cannot connect to it "`Auth fail`" and the socket reaches its timeout.

Try to ping the server to see its response. Make sure you give the same ip address you use in the program. If you directly provide the server name, check your [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) `/etc/hosts` on Linux or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: I don't think that this is the answer to the question from MAHI. The question is, how to differentiate the errors? Is a string comparison required? Are there better ways to interpret the error?

Answer (score 0):

ADD below nuget packages to your solution

1. DiffieHellman
2. Org.Mentalis.Security